# Basic server optimization – Slow server with 1 connection

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, server, unicorn

My server runs incredibly slowly... with no traffic at all apart from myself. I am proxying Unicorn server with Nginx. I know very little about server optimisation. A total of 13 seconds first loading time to 10 on second.

Network:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aHf9.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S7Vi.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4IuJ.png

What is the quickest way for me to shave 10 seconds off it?

**Note:** Assets have not been precompiled.

**Edit:** If I cut Nginx out of the process and serve directly to Unicorn I'm down to 1.72 seconds. It looks as if Nginx is the great culprit. I still don't have a clue why Nginx is slowing me down so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so...

The bottleneck was indeed due to Nginx or rather the interplay between Nginx and Unicorn. It was not resolved until I made Unicorn and Nginx agree on a socket in their respective configuration files.

Unicorn needed this:

```
listen ENV["UNICORN_PORT"].to_i || 4567, :tcp_nopush => true
listen "#{@dir}tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64
```

and nginx needed an upstream configuration pointing to the socket.

```
upstream unicorn_server {
    server unix:/home/user/someapp/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
    fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Server first response time is now down to 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out where the bottleneck is. It is hard to guess just by the network graphs, but you should check the following levels in your system:

- OS level - if it has enough resources: processor usage, load avg, memory (is system swapping?)
- Database level - it is most probable that bottleneck would be here as you have your issue with only 1 session; trace and check the queries which DB runs and tune them up (indexes, statistics, depends on DB server); check the database locks while the appserver is running
- Application server level - well, it depends on the application itself, but it would be good to review the code it is running; maybe it is waiting for something, like response from the external system?

Comment: Thanks for your input.

I just tried connecting directly to port 3000 (on which I am running Unicorn server). Load time is now a total of 1.72 seconds. That's down from 13 seconds...

So, I think it's fair to say that Nginx's proxying is the bottleneck?

Comment: That would be very strange - it is just a proxy, it just transmits a requests, so it should be quick. Is this behavior repetitive? It might be a coincidence (first request is slow, the second faster because caches are filled up etc). And what I am thinking, maybe the DNS resolves slow?

Comment: since this turns out to be a configuration issue, I'm thinking that without proper configuration Nginx searches all of the sockets until it finds a connection–that might explain the delay?

Comment: Yes, it could be an explanation